# Custom event with cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm trying to write some game with `cocos2d-x`, and I'm trying to define some custom event like `on_game_start`, `on_game_end` etc. I searched the forum and googled the web, there seems to be no too much mentions about this. So, anyone please give me some tips on this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "event"?

Comment: By event, I mean somethings like touch event, key event etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is not such things as global event in cocos2d-x. So I tried to use CCNotificationCenter as an alternative.

Here is the code how I used:

```
//Send event.
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification(EMEMY_KILLED_MSG, (CCObject*)data);

//Listen event.
void GameManager::initListener()
{
    CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->addObserver(this, callfuncO_selector(GameManager::onEnemyKilled), CLICK_TEST_MSG, NULL);
}

//Handling event
void GameManager::onEnemyKilled(CCObject* obj)
{
    CCMessageBox("onEnemyKilled", "Title");

    //Remove event listener.
    CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->removeObserver(this, EMEMY_KILLED_MSG);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your "custom event" equals "function call when enter/exit a game scene". So you can write a initialize function like `void on_game_start()` and add it to scene's function `onEnterTransitionDidFinish()`, which is automatically called by the engine. Also you need to implement your own scene class inherited from `CCScene`, don't forget to implement this `onEnterTransitionDidFinish()` virtual function in your own sub-class.

Comment: Hi, Rect, thanks for the reply. I'd like to have some events like on_game_start, on_enemy_killed etc., which could be distributed globally rather than scene or node based callbacks, somethings like key & touch events.

Comment: That's not a "callback", if you read touch events' source code, you can see it was implemented by a class which can also be treat like a "delegate" in Obj-C. You can try to implement your own.